# Problems with CanCan Methods with Rails3 / Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

After two days, I've not been able to solve this problem on my own. It seems like it should be pretty simple, but I'm missing something. I'm creating a simple blog with Posts and Authors. Authors have a boolean admin column.

The line that is giving me an error right now is where I check permissions to show the edit button in a post.Current error is:

NoMethodError in Posts#show

Showing .../posts/show.html.erb where line #18 raised:

undefined method `stringify_keys' for #

**posts/show.html.rb**

```
          <% if @author.can? :update, @post %>
          <p><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post), :class => 'btn' %> &nbsp; <%= link_to 'Destroy', @post, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></p>
          <% end %>
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery  
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to root_url, :alert => exception.message
  end
  helper_method :current_author
  def current_user
    @current_ability ||= Author.new(current_author)
  end
end
```

**ability.rb**

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(author)
    author ||= Author.new # guest user (not logged in)   
    if author.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end  
  end
end
```

Also, from what I can tell, CanCan is included in the gem file correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.

First, you need to have a `current_user` method in your controller, on which cancan relies. If you don't have one, you may

- alias `current_user` to your `current_whatever` method or
- manually instantiate the ability like `@ability = Ability.new(current_whatever)` and call your `can?`'s on that generated ability in your views (like `@ability.can? :edit, @post`).

Second, your `Ability` uses `current_author` on both line 4 and 5, however you don't have a `current_author` in your `initialize` method. You have `author`, though. If no `Author` object is available/given to the ability's initializer, you use a non-persisted author instead (and not a AuthorAbility, unless your AuthorAbility is what `current_user` returns or `initialize` in your ability gets as argument). Something like this:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(author)
    author ||= Author.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if author.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end  
  end
end
```

---

Edit based on the comments to keep it simpler:

Ideally you put a `current_user` method inside your application controller and also make it available as helper in your views (because you may want to conditionally show/hide/change things in your view based on a logged-in user).

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :current_user

  def current_user
    # return the currently logged in user record
  end
end
```

If this is new to you, I suggest to have a look at an authentication gem. Devise also introduces this and authlogic describes this in its how-to and the example application. If you're doing authentication from scratch, you just need to return the user based on the session.

---

edit 2. You actually need to understand what you do, which IMHO is not the case at the moment. You're doing a bit of a  mess here ;-)

Problem 1: `current_user` needs to return the **current author / user logged in** (not an abilty nor fallback user nor something else) or `nil` if no author is logged in. So you can e.g. do `<% if current_user %>` in your view. `@current_ability ||= Author.new(current_author)` is plain wrong. The fallback from the ability class needs to stay in the ability class because cancan's methods can only be applied to an object and not to `nil`. So with `author ||= Author.new` in your ability, you make sure that there is an object, even if no author is logged in (in which case `current_author` returns `nil`).

Problem 2: `helper_method :current_author` actually does nothing because there is no `current_author` method in your application controller. You need to somehow define `current_author`.

Problem 3: In your view, you're calling `can?` on an instance of `Author` which is wrong. `can?` is a method of `Ability`. So you'd need to use `@my_ability.can?` where @my_ability is an instance of e.g. `Ability.new(Author.first)`. This is used if you need to work with multiple abilities or customized something, which is not the case here, so just use `can?` directly without a receiver (like `@author.can?`).

For testing purposes, I'd create the following:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :current_user # as defined below...

  def current_user
    # Return a static user here, for testing purposes,
    # like @current_user = User.first or Author.first
  end
end
```

So your `current_user` returns a valid user (I hope, you need to at least have one in your database stored, though) and then can sort out the ability issues. If your ability works, you implement your authentication. As a beginner, I'd either stick to [authlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) or [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

Comment: Can you let me know what the current_(author in this case) method should look like in my controller? I don't see anything about it in the Getting Started documentation. https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Comment: Huh? First sentence in https://github.com/ryanb/cancan#getting-started ... also, https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/changing-defaults. current_user returns an instance of the user currently logged in.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to all of this. My eyes skipped right over that sentence and went to point 1. When it says "CanCan expects a current_user method to exist in the controller" does it mean the Application Controller, the Authors Controller or the Posts Controller? Second, what should that method look like? The second section on Changing Defaults? Thank you.

Comment: Updated with a new error. I was getting this same error a while back. Not sure if it's closer or further now.

Comment: FWIW I'm also using Friendly_ID for the URLS, not sure if it is affecting anything.

Comment: See my edit. friendlyId does not create your problems, the missing understanding is the problem ;-)

Comment: Yes, I know that's the case. Thanks for you help though. I'm going to dive deeper into your comments and think about this for another day or so. I appreciate your patience. Also seems like I'm complicating this by using Authors instead of Users.

Comment: no problem. mh, not necessarily, but for the beginning, I'd start with `User` until you feel comfortable with how things are working.

Comment: I got it, thank you! @current_user = current_author in ability.rb worked.